# Input start date, then # of days to complete, and then have excel come up with end date.. possible?

Tags: excel, date

I'm working on a farm plan and need to set dates.

I have a beginning date in one column and the avg number of days to complete in the next. Is there an Excel program to calculate the end date? Or is this something I will have to do manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add manually. Using the add/sum formula

`=A2+B2`
[image]